# git: how to deploy .gitattributes from its git repository to the client?

Tags: git, configuration, client

Good evening

we have a git repository:

```
…\repository\.git\
…\repository\any repository dirs\
```

and we have to force that all users automatically get this configuration in .gitattributes if they copy our repository:

```
# Disable all EOL conversation on checkout to the working directory
*   -text
```

I understand the [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) that .gitattributes for a repository must be saved here:

```
…\repository\.git\info\.gitattributes
```

Unfortunately, it looks like ".git\info\.gitattributes" is not part of the repository itself :-(

Therefore we have this strange question:
how can we automatically deploy a git repository configuration to the client if the configuration is not part of the repository?

Thanks a lot for any help!
kind regards, Tom

Comment: I've tried different settings and studied different docs for some hours - and the docs are really annoying in this question. Therefore I asked for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot, @paulsm4, for your answer - but it's not the solution.

After some more investigation I've found this answer:

1. .gitattributes can be placed in the repository root (parallel to the .git directory) and then .gitattributes is applied for all handled files of this repository.
2. .gitattributes can also be placed in any subdirectory to be just applied to the files in this subdirectory
3. .git/info/attributes can be used it one don't want the attributes file committed to the repository

Therefore, the answer to my question is:

```
…\repository\.git\
…\repository\.gitattributes    » will we applied to all handled files in the repository
```

Kind regards,
Tom